# Can not read observable Json content items within my template though I managed to display them on my typescript file

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

Under Ionic4 and within a component, I called a service that returns an observable. I managed to display part of the Json structure elements  but I can not do it within my template.

```
// WeatherService.ts
 getWeather(item):Observable<Weather>

  {
    this.ApIurl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${item.city}&units=metric&appid=${this.apikey}`;

  // console.log(this.ApIurl);
    return this.http.get<Weather>(this.ApIurl);
  }
```

```
//details.ts
// weatherS declared of type WeatherService

this.weatherS.getWeather(this.locationDetails)
      .subscribe(
        dt => {
          this.data$ = dt; 
// display temperature works fine
console.log(this.data.main.temp);
```

```
//json content  returned 

  {
        "temp": 23,
        "pressure": 1015,
        "humidity": 64,
        "temp_min": 22,
        "temp_max": 24
    }
```

unfortunately I can not display within my template details.html   data$.temp or any other values though I manage to display the whole structure with {{data$ | json}}

Comment: What is even `this.data.main.temp`? You have no `data` anywhere, but `data$`. If that is a typo, you need to show in template for example with `data$.main.temp` instead of `data$.temp`. Also use safe navigation operator to safeguard null values: `{{data$?.main?.temp}}`

Comment: **main**  is an array within the Json data returned. it has many keys and   **temp** is one of them.    Thanks guys   I did not realized that I had to deal with null values within my asynchronous data. All  you answers fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use syntax with ? sign like below (example from my app, that also uses this weather api). At the end of answer, more info about ?.

```
<li>Temperature: {{result?.main?.temp}}</li>
```

In your example, I hope so this should look like this:

```
{{data?.main?.temp}}
```

If you want be sure about displaying your value in template, use:

```
<div *ngIf="data.length > 0">
    {{data?temp}}
</div>
```

? - Safe navigator helps you dealing with async data, that can not exists when template renders. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data of an observable in templates by using `async` pipe:

```
{{data$ | async | json}}
```

Comment: why is this upvoted? `data$` is not an observable according to the code and OP says they can display the response with `data$ | json` which would indeed mean it's not an observable.